# How do I find the reference/identifier of a button on the storyboard in xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Thanks for reading; this is my problem, I'm trying to hook up code I have written to buttons which already exist in the storyboard but I can't find a reference or identifier for the button(s).

I want to be able to modify buttons which have been created on the storyboard and style/give actions in my code.

So I would like something I can reference like so:
    UIButton ***subBtn**;

where subBtn is the button's reference/identifier.

tldr; where do you find the reference for buttons in xcode (v6+) storyboard?

Comment: `IBoutlet`? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: assign them tags in the storyboard (I'm pretty sure it's possible) and then identify the buttons by those tags

Comment: @Larme No I'm looking for a specific identifier for buttons from the storyboard, for example, if I look in the attributes tab I would expect an attribute named "variable name" or something like that, that is what I seek.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come after me:

```
UIButton *subBtn = (UIButton *) [self.view viewWithTag:9];
```

The Line above allows you to reference a button with an "tag" which you can find in the attributes tab in the storyboard.

By using this it allows you to change attributes like below, to format your buttons:

```
[subBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(submitHit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIImage *UISubImg = [UIImage imageNamed: @"submit_button.png"];
UIImage *UISubImg2 = [UIImage imageNamed: @"submit-play-icon.png"];
[subBtn setTitle:@"SUBMIT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
subBtn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 400, 280, 65);
[self.view addSubview:subBtn];
[subBtn setBackgroundImage:UISubImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[subBtn setImage:UISubImg2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

SubmitHit is a method.